# CryptoGraffiti.info litecoin alternative

Tags: blockchain-data-storage

I have some pictures and litecoins, and I would like to be able to upload images to the litecoin blockchain. I also have some bitcoin, but, because of the higher value of bitcoin, I think I would prefer to use the litecoin because it allows more uploads. There is a site called CryptoGraffiti.info that charges bitcoin and bitcoin SV. I thought about using the bitcoin SV, but that would require buying additional crypto, which I can afford (the big BTC, only a couple images for hundreds of $) and Litecoin is both significantly cheaper and more well maintained than Bitcoin SV. So, I want to know how to upload an image to litecoin using this type of tool.

Note: I want to use this to upload original pictures of things like New York City  and my home town.

Comment: Note: It *should* be expensive, you're basically paying for your data to be processed and stored on tens of thousands (!) of computers around the world.

Comment: Note: this site doesn't support bitcoin, only BSV.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find much on writing data to the litecoin blockchain, you might need to code something yourself, perhaps taking the data you want to upload, chunk it and write it by using many transactions. To read it back you need to read these transactions from the blockchain and put the data chunks back together.

If I were you I would look into Ethereum instead. Ethereum has the ability to let you write customized smart contracts that can accept files/pictures data and store it forever on the Eth blockchain. If this gets too expensive you can offload storage using IPFS, so that the Eth blockchain would need to store only the hash of the files instead of the whole files.